# How can I increase my war score when the enemy is fully conquered?

Tags: stellaris

I am fighting an enemy and I set just a single war goal with score 94. I already destroyed all their fleets and all their spaceports and I'm occupying all their planets, but I still haven't reached that score, and so I can't finish that war with any advantage.

Is there anything else I can do to increase my war score score, other than waiting? For instance, should I bother hunting down all their non-military stations?

Comment: Sue for white peace?

Comment: @DCShannon That's what I'll do if I can't find a way to increase my score. The question is, is there such a way :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-military stations do add to war score if destroyed (they count as a battle), so if that's literally all they have left and can produce no more ships, go hunt them down.

Comment: Well, turns out that they had a hidden system somewhere, and occupying it sealed the deal. But I did notice non-military stations give war score, as you wrote, and it seems like a good way to get those last few points.

Answer (score 3):

You do not (despite what you might think), require 100 warscore in order to end the war.

Simply bring up diplomacy with your enemy and select your single wargoal. Whether or not they choose to accept your terms depends on their relative warscore (though 91 is a lot for a single planet, so I assume you would be fine) + other factors, such as relative military strength and length of war (with having a much smaller army increasing their willingness to negotiate, as does war that has been going on for longer times).

If you do not select the war goal, this method will offer white peace instead.

Comment: My point is, I only have a single war goal, and it's higher than the current war score. I realize I can go with white peace instead, my question is whether there's a way to increase my score.

Comment: @Oak I'm not suggesting a White Peace - the capitulation mechanics mean you can get more wargoals with the same warscore as Time / Fleet Power changes.